# Problem with SQL select statment

Tags: sql

Ok I can't figure this one out I have

```
select job "Some job", Count(a.bossID) "Number Of bosses" 
from boss a, places b, place_boss ba 
where ba.bossid = a.bossid and ba.placeid = b.placeid 
   and Count(a.bossID)>1 
group by job;
```

I  get Group function not allowed here I need make sure that if the job has one boss it doesn't show.

Any Idea what I'm messing up here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `having`. The `Where` clause cannot contain aggregates. Additionally I have changed it to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax as this is (IMO) clearer and less likely to cause inadvertent Cartesian joins.

```
select job             "Some job",
       Count(a.bossID) "Number Of bosses"
from   boss a
       join place_boss ba
         on ba.bossid = a.bossid
       join places b
         on ba.placeid = b.placeid
group  by job
having Count(a.bossID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`where` clauses are applied at the row level, literally a "should this row be included in the result set". At the time that decision is being made, it's impossible for the `count()` function to have finished its work, as not all rows have been counted yet.

That's where `having` clauses come in to play. They're exactly like `where` clauses, but applied immediately before the result set gets sent to the client, after the aggregate functions have completed their work.

Technically, doing

```
SELECT * FROM table HAVING somefield='a'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE somefield='a'
```

are identical, except the having clause will entail a bit more work on the part of the server because all the rows are fetched, THEN filtered, rather than being filtered before fetching.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    job "Some job", 
    Count(a.bossID) "Number Of bosses"  
from 
    boss a, places b, place_boss ba  
where 
    ba.bossid = a.bossid and ba.placeid = b.placeid  
group by job
having Count(a.bossID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try it with a HAVING clause:

```
select job "Some job", Count(a.bossID) "Number Of bosses" 
from boss a, places b, place_boss ba 
where ba.bossid = a.bossid 
group by job
having Count(a.bossID)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it should be

```
select job "Some job", Count(a.bossID) "Number Of bosses" from boss a, places b, place_boss ba where ba.bossid = a.bossid and ba.placeid = b.placeid group by job having Count(a.bossID)>1;
```

Comment: Opps already 3 answers, holy crap. I'll accept Martins when I can!

Comment: "Nevermind"?  I'd accept an answer.  Reminds of that joke about the Irishman who was looking for a parking spot without success.  He swore that if God would give him a parking space he'd give up the whiskey and go back to church every Sunday.  Just as he finished his prayer a space miraculously opened before him.  "Nevermind," he said, "I found one!"

Comment: I was going to :P I posted my answer without refreshing hence the "I'll accept Martins when I can!" :)